# Copy whole page html source

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the below script to copy a whole page's HTML code.

This works and copies the whole page however it also includes the 'Copy HTML' button code.

How can I include everything but this?

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';
  textArea.style.padding = 0;
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnDate").click(function() {
    var allHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    copyTextToClipboard(allHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Copy only this</h1>
<h2>And this</h2>
<p>And this but not the button below</p>
<button type="button" id="btnDate" class="btn btn-primary">Copy HTML</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate, remove it and put it back

NOTE: There is a [newer way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) to interact with the clipboard

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';
  textArea.style.padding = 0;
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click","#btnDate",function() {
    const $btn = $(this).clone()
    $(this).remove()
    var allHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    copyTextToClipboard(allHTML);
    $("body").append($btn)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Copy only this</h1>
<h2>And this</h2>
<p>And this but not the button below</p>
<button type="button" id="btnDate" class="btn btn-primary">Copy HTML</button>
```